# Promise resolve fires before task is complete

Tags: node.js, promise, restify

I'm using a promise function and [Jimp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp) to resize an image, save it in a folder, and then return the path to the new resized image.

However, the `resolve()` function in `resizeWidth()` is fired before `image.resize().write()` is done, which means my app crashes because it cannot find the new file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const jimp = require('jimp');

const resizeWidth = function(file, width) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    jimp.read(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'assets', 'images', file), (err, image) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      const xSize = parseInt(width);
      image.resize(xSize, jimp.AUTO)
        .write(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'assets', 'images', 'tmp', file));
      resolve(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'assets', 'images', 'tmp', file));
    });
  });
};

module.exports = function(server) {
  server.get('/images/:name/:width', (req, res) => {
    resizeWidth(req.params.name, req.params.width)
      .then(() => {
        fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'assets', 'images', 'tmp', req.params.name),
          (err, newData) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.sendRaw(200, newData, {
              'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(newData)
            });
            res.end();
          });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  });
};
```

Comment: You can just do `path.join(__dirname, '../assets/images/tmp', file)`, mind. Note also that `throw err` will kill your server; I’d suggest using a promisified version of `fs.readFile`.

Comment: @Ryan, yeah this is just a preliminary test to see if jimp lives up to the project requirements - refactoring will take care of the things you mention.

Comment: Oh, and definitely do not read and respond with the contents of `path.join(…, 'tmp', req.params.name)` without validating or transforming `req.params.name` unless you want clients to have read/write access (depending on permissions – both are equally bad) to any file on your system with `?name=../../sensitive-config`. I recommend a UUID or a hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

write is asynchronous function so that resolve is called before write function is complete. Use callback to ensure order

```
jimp.read(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'assets', 'images', file), (err, image) => {
  if (err) reject(err);
  const xSize = parseInt(width);
  image.resize(xSize, jimp.AUTO)
    .write(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'assets', 'images', 'tmp', file), () => {
       resolve(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'assets', 'images', 'tmp', file));
    });
});
```

Comment: Ridiculously simple solution. Thank you!

Comment: @BrianEmilius If this works, please accept this answer. If not, please comment on this answer which another problem happens. I'll try to help.